# Change URL in Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel

I have a legacy project and I am trying to install `Laravel` in the project.

I have added a subfolder in my existing projects `www` directory and changed the `.htaccess` to following

```
RewriteEngine on

# for 2nd project
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?users /blog/public/index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/?users/(.*)$ /blog/public/index.php/$1 [QSA,L]

# quick links
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/user_files/
RewriteRule ^([^\.\?]+)$        /mod_rewrite_delegator.php?keyword=$1   [QSA,L]
```

It works fine for both projects but for my new laravel project the URL looks long and I want to change it to something easy to read.

For example, http://myproject.dev/blog/public/index.php/home should be http://myproject.dev/blog 
Or http://myproject.dev/blog/public/index.php/contact should be http://myproject.dev/blog/contact

How can I rewrite the URL?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You would want something like:

```
Redirect /blog /
```

right?

Or for laravel specific I use:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

(last rule is the public rewrite rule)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: should I add this in my existing project's `.htaccess` or in laravel's `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your looking something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  ^blog/(.*)$ /blog/public/index.php/ [L]
```

Basically it will remove `/public/index.php/`.

Comment: does not work. I have an existing project in `www` folder and I have installed Laravel in `www/blog` folder. I added your code in `www/.htaccess` but it is not working.

Comment: You edited right .htaccess. I just edited my answer and tested on my virtual machine this one should work without any issue please try updated one.